# scroll snap long content

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll-snap

I have the container set to `scroll-snap-type: Mandatory`, And It always snaps either to the top of the element or the top of the one below, making the middle part of the tall element impossible to scroll.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

I tried to set height when the content was longer than a wrapper. it didn't solve my problem, especially on mobile.

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".scroll-container");
let scrollItem = document.querySelectorAll(".scroll-item");

scrollItem.forEach((e) => {
  let outerH = e.scrollHeight;
  let innerH = e.querySelector(".item-inner").scrollHeight;

  if (outerH < innerH) {
    e.classList.add("noSnap");
    e.style.height = innerH + 60 + "px";
  }
});
```

```css
.scroll-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.scroll-item {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.scroll-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<main>
  <div class="scroll-container text-center" id="overflow-scroll">
    <div class="scroll-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center lazyload">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center lazyload">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum howdy</p>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <p>
          long content end
        </p>
        <p>
          lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center lazyload">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Long content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center lazyload">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum howdy</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```